# I can't access port forwarding containers

Tags: docker, apache, docker-image

I tried to run a `httpd` container with the following command:

```
docker container run -d -p 8080:80 httpd
```

but when I access `localhost:8080`, I always get this error `ERR_CONNECTION_RESET`

Comment: Maybe try to include more information about your particular setup. What OS are you using, and how did you install Docker? Are you using any virtual machine?

Answer (score 0):

it seems some other process is using port 80.
you can reset ports by resetting IP tables.

- stop docker service
- reset IP tables

  ```
    iptables -P FORWARD ACCEPT
    iptables -P OUTPUT ACCEPT
    iptables -t nat -F
    iptables -t mangle -F
    iptables -F
    iptables -X
  ```
- reset Docker Service

Comment: I'm afraid it didn't work, I'm still getting ERR_CONNECTION_RESET on my browser